# Could I connect a eGPU to my monitor and have the monitor connect to the laptop?

Tags: display, graphics-card

I want to get a eGPU for my laptop, but I am just wondering what would happen if I connect a GPU to a monitor, connect to the pcie slot on the egpu dock, will it work still? Let's say this: I have a monitor for my laptop, connected through HDMI, and I connect a GPU with another HDMI cable to the monitor. Will the computer recognize the GPU connected to the monitor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Downvoters: can you explain what's wrong with this question and how it should be improved?

Answer (score 1):

It would be recognized as two independent monitors and the computer would try to display on "both".

Your could try to configure Windows to use only the eGPU display when it's connected. Combined with automatic input switching on the monitor this could work reasonably well. The benefit of that is you don't waste PCI-e bandwidth to send video signal back to the laptop for displaying.

Comment: Will it show my laptop's display on the monitor?

Comment: It will work like any multi-display setup. You'll be able to choose to clone the built-in display or extend it.

Comment: Is there a tutorial on how to do something like that online? And will it install the graphics drivers?

Comment: It's pretty basic stuff, just use google. It really works just like any multi-display setup. Will what install the drivers? You should already have drivers for the eGPU installed. Monitors don't need drivers.

Comment: so it does not need PCIE? I can just plug it in and not waste my wifi card?

Comment: Plug what where? That's very vague and confusing. Your question was about connecting a monitor to the eGPU but it sounds like you're asking about connecting the eGPU to a laptop now? It won't just magically talk to the eGPU because it's lying on the same desk - you need PCI-e.